# Erro ao passar array como parâmetro para objeto do Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent, slim

Estou tendo problemas para inserir um registro do tipo 1:N usando Eloquent. Quando eu passo o array com os atributos para o objeto como a documentação orienta um erro é lançado e quando eu imprimo o erro com `echo $ex->getMessage()` a única coisa que é impressa é "numero", que é o index que eu dou ao array que eu estou passando. Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

```
public static function cadastrar(Request $request, Response $response) {
    try {
        $dadosCambista = $request->getParsedBody();

        $cambista = new \Cambista;
        $cambista->nome = $dadosCambista['nome'];
        $cambista->flagAtivo = $dadosCambista['flagAtivo'];
        $cambista->limiteDiario = $dadosCambista['limiteDiario'];
        $cambista->limiteIndividual = $dadosCambista['limiteIndividual'];
        $cambista->limiteCasadinha = $dadosCambista['limiteCasadinha'];
        $cambista->comissao1 = $dadosCambista['comissao1'];
        $cambista->comissao2 = $dadosCambista['comissao2'];
        $cambista->comissao3 = $dadosCambista['comissao3'];
        $cambista->login = $dadosCambista['login'];
        $cambista->senha = md5(SALT . $dadosCambista['senha']);
        $cambista->idRegional = $dadosCambista['idRegional'];
        //$cambista->save();

        foreach ($dadosCambista['telefones'] as $key => $numero) {
            $telefones[$key] = new \Telefone(array("numero" => $numero));
        }

        $cambista->telefones()->saveMany($telefones);

        $meta = Helper::retornaMetaArray(Enum::SUCS_STS, Enum::CREATED, 201);

        return $response->withCustomJson(null, $meta);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $meta = Helper::retornaMetaArray(Enum::ERR_STS, $ex->getMessage(), 400);

        return $response->withCustomJson(null, $meta);
    }
}
```

Isso é o que está sendo enviado no corpo da mensagem.:

```
{
    "nome": "Jon Snow",
    "login": "jon",
    "senha": "ghost",
    "flagAtivo": "1",
    "limiteDiario": "500.00",
    "limiteIndividual": "50.00",
    "limiteCasadinha": "100.00",
    "comissao1": "5",
    "comissao2": "7",
    "comissao3": "10",
    "idRegional": "1",
    "telefones": ["(82) 99178-1066", "(82) 99303-9037"]
}
```

O objeto Cambista está sendo cadastrado no banco porém os seus números de telefone não.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que o `saveMany` do telefone não está correto. Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$cambista->telefones()->saveMany([
    new \Telefone(["numero" => "(82) 99178-1066"]),
    new \Telefone(["numero" => "(82) 99303-9037"]);
]);
```

Comment: Ainda dá o mesmo erro. Obrigado por responder.

Comment: Resolveu?

Como está as tabelas?

Comment: Eu ajustei o o método no model Cambista para:

public function telefones() {
        return $this->hasMany('\Telefone', 'idCambista', 'id');
    }

Aparentemente tava errado a ordem das chaves já que eu tenho que sobrescrever o padrão do Eloquent por ter os nomes diferentes do que ele espera. Mas o mais estranho é que o erro lançado não me dizia nada. De qualquer maneira agradeço bastante a resposta. Abraço.